# Display outputted data in my Form so i can edit

Tags: php, html, forms, content-management-system, file-get-contents

How can i display the outputted data that is (contents.html) to go in my form textarea (edit.html). I am using a JS HTML WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) in the form page to make it easier for people with no HTML experience to make edits.

(i am aware of XSS attacks but i'd just like to get this working for now.)
I have tried echo but it will not work, anyone know how i can achieve this?

Regards

**edit.php**
*// Submits form data to contents.html*

```
<?php file_put_contents("content.html", print_r($_POST['content'], true)); ?>
<form method="post">
<textarea name="content" style="width:960px; margin: 0 auto;" rows="20" cols="20">


</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**contents.html**

*// Blank until something is submitted with the form*

**index.php**

*// Retrieves data from contents.html and displays it*

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('content.html');?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is actually getting written to that file?  And that the path is correct on the file_get_contents call?

Comment: when i go on content.html its been written there and when i go to index.php its also been echoed to that file. I just want to be able to display it in the data i've inputted form text area so i can actually edit instead of overwritting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the contents in the textarea, *after* escaping it. This will prevent XSS in your form (edit.php), and cause the HTML contents to be shown correctly.

The if-statement checks whether the form has been submitted or not. If that's true, the contents from `$_POST['content']` will be written to `content.html`. Note: `isset($_POST['save'])` and `name="save"` are optional for checking whether the form has been submitted or not, but if you've multiple submit options (e.g., a preview button), it's required.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']) && filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'content')){
    file_put_contents("content.html", filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'content'));
}
?>

<form method="post">
<textarea name="content" style="width:960px; margin: 0 auto;" rows="20" cols="20"><?php
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("content.html"));
?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: When i click submit it will display the content but if i reload the page that data will disappear. I am not sure if this issue is caused by the PHP statement above the form.

Comment: Yep, it was. Please look at my answer again.